# Passing MessageProducer as argument, how can I create a message?

Tags: java, jms

I'm *trying out* some JMS messaging and I created a class design where a the constructor takes in a `MessageConsumer` and a `MessageProducer`. The class is supposed to both consume and produce messages. On the other hand it should not contain the plumbing / identifiers necessary for setting up the sessions or the consumers / producers, let alone ESB specific code.

Now for some reason it seems possible to directly use the `MessageConsumer` to receive messages. It seems however impossible to use `MessageProducer` and *create* messages and then "produce" them on the messaging service.

So how should I design this kind of class?

---

Small example, consider a method with a single parameter, is it possible to somehow create messages without passing a `session` parameter?

```
void sendApplicationSpecificMessage(MessageProducer producer) {
    // how to create a message here?
}
```

Comment: The producer is used to send the message not create it (although why a producer is not a message factory isn't clear.)

Comment: message object is created using Session object. Producer is used to send the message that is created using the session object

Comment: So I cannot somehow create message other than passing the session, with all the methods and responsibility that comes with it? Or could I possibly pass a smaller interface than `Session`?

Comment: Hmm, this could be resolved by creating a single method `getMessageFactory()` to `MessageProducer`. Then the `MessageFactory` interface has to define the calls currently in `Session`. I'll make a feature request (which, in turn, would just call the right methods of `Session` (or internal method implementations), of course.